# How does Phoenix translate IN clause?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

Are there performance differences in Apache Phoenix between doing a query like:
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column IN ('A')` 
and 
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'A'`?

Same question between: `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column IN ('A','B')` 
and `SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'A' OR Column = 'B'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of:
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column IN ('A','B')`
It uses java Set under the hoot. So the time complexity is O(1). See [InListExpression](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/master/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/phoenix/expression/InListExpression.java) for more details.

In case of:
`SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column = 'A' OR Column = 'B'`
It uses linear comparison under the hood. So the time complexity if O(n). See [OrExpression](https://github.com/apache/phoenix/blob/master/phoenix-core/src/main/java/org/apache/phoenix/expression/OrExpression.java) for more details.

So yes, it seems like there is a significant performance difference between these two statements if we speak about decent amount of data.